# Is there a way a video can be encoded on its own when uploaded into server

Tags: php, html, ffmpeg, mysqli

Below is my code where it uploads a file into a server and stores the names of each uploaded file into the db:

```
<?php

 // connect to the database
 include('connect.php');

  /* check connection */
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    die();
  }


    if ($_FILES['fileVideo']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) { 

$result = 0;


if( file_exists("VideoFiles/".$_FILES['fileVideo']['name'])) {
    $parts = explode(".",$_FILES['fileVideo']['name']);
    $ext = array_pop($parts);
    $base = implode(".",$parts);
    $n = 2;

    while( file_exists("VideoFiles/".$base."_".$n.".".$ext)) $n++;
    $_FILES['fileVideo']['name'] = $base."_".$n.".".$ext;

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileVideo"]["tmp_name"],
    "VideoFiles/" . $_FILES["fileVideo"]["name"]);
    $result = 1;

}
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileVideo"]["tmp_name"],
      "VideoFiles/" . $_FILES["fileVideo"]["name"]);
      $result = 1;
  }

    $videosql = "INSERT INTO Video (VideoFile) 
    VALUES (?)";

        if (!$insert = $mysqli->prepare($videosql)) {
      // Handle errors with prepare operation here
    }

    //Assign the variable
$vid = 'VideoFiles/'.$_FILES['fileVideo']['name'];

            //Dont pass data directly to bind_param store it in a variable
$insert->bind_param("s",$vid);

 $insert->execute();
 $id = $mysqli->insert_id;

        if ($insert->errno) {
          // Handle query error here
        }

        $insert->close();     

        }else{
  echo "Upload was not successful";   
  }

?>

 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 window.top.stopVideoUpload(<?php echo $result; ?>,'<?php echo $id; ?>', '<?php echo $_FILES['fileVideo']['name']; ?>');
 </script>  

</body>
</html>
```

Now I am using a jwplayer and it requires video files to match video formats on this page:

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12539/supported-video-and-audio-formats/

So I need to be able to encode files automatically on the server when the file is uploaded into the server. I do not want the user to try and encode a video file manually by themseleves, I want it done automatically. But my question is how can I get automatic server side file encoding to work?

I have a demo showing how a video file is uploaded: [DEMO](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/InputTest2.php)

To use Demo:

1. Click on `Add Question` button and file input will appear in table
2. Click on upload straightaway and you will see a simple validation stating which video file format are allowed (this is simply done by checking video file extension)
3. Browse for a video file, select and then click on `Upload` and wait for upload to finish (I recommend a short video file for saving time). When file is uploaded it will display success message and video file is uploaded into server,

Comment: *encode* can mean a few different things, what do  you specify want to happen to the file?

Comment: Encoding video-files to a different format has MANY options. First of all, the original file needs to be analyzed, because video-files with the same file-extension can use different 'codecs' and even videos with the same codec, might use different settings for that codec that are not supported by the player. Of course, I don't know the exact purpose of the website, but have you considered having people upload the video to YouTube and paste the embed-url? This will save you the encoding process, end save you hard disk space

Comment: @Dagon I mean if you look at the format videos for jwplayer link in question, I want .mp4 files to be ` H.264 codec`, .webm to be ` VP8 encoded` .ogg to be `Theora encoded` and .flv to be `VP6 codec`

Comment: @thaJeztah Ok, the videos will be displayed in an online examination as some questions may require viewing a video. So I believe youtube even though I read is very good as it does things automatically, will not be good to use in an exam

Comment: @thaJeztah I have to assume a tacher with no computer skills at all is trying to upload a video, that's why I need a lot of things to be done automatically?

Comment: So the user that manages the questions will have to upload the videos? Even for those situations, YouTube may be a good option. The user can upload the video to YouTube, but sets it to 'unlisted', that way only people that *know* the url are able to watch it. If the url to that video is pasted in the website, you'll be able to show it. Info on 'unlisted' videos: http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=157177

Comment: If you write down some short instructions, you'll be able to teach the teacher how to upload a video to YouTube. YouTube has all the software in place to convert the video to the right formats, so you won't need to do that

Comment: @thaJeztah I will have to keep it as I have it. Problem is that I am uploading images ,videos and audios using the same uploader I have now. I havn't got time for an alternative as I really need to get this done today. I am already lost in what to do and I will definilty go for this way in the future

Comment: @user1930247 Use H.264 and AAC or MP3 in mp4 or flv, and VP8 and Vorbis in webm. Theora and VP6 are a waste of time.

Comment: @user1930247 Having the option of uploading 'any' type of video-file and automatically convert it to the supported video-formats will be very hard to implement, especially in the given time-frame. I don't think I'll be able to help you with that, but hope you succeed. Atb!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many ways of doing that. The easiest and fastest in terms of programmer time is to use ffmpeg to directly encode the thing into something useable, right in your upload script (use `exec` or `system` to do so).

This imposes some problems though: your browser might drop in a timeout when the server is too busy processing the request. Also, you cannot really spread the load.

So, after the upload is succesfull, you call ffmpeg:

```
exec("ffmpeg -i $vid -vcodec libx264 -vpre default -crf 21 ".
                      "-acodec libfaac -ab 128k $vid-transcoded.mp4");
```

You will have to refer to the [`ffmpeg`](http://ffmpeg.org/) website for all options (there are **a lot** of them). Also, jwplayer is quite popular, so there should be many resources on how to transcode it.

So, another solution is to have the server upload files in a `to_be_processed` directory and have a background process (cronjob perhaps?) to process all files in that dir. That way, the browser request is done when the upload is done and you are in full control of processing resources. This, however, takes a considerate amount of programmer time. You will have to create the processing job, as well as do some administration work to let the user know how far the processing is.

Comment: Which way would you do it between the two? The videos will be stored in an exam so would you do it by ffmpeg or to_be_processed way?

Comment: Depends on how the systems will be used. If it is for a play project that will never get many visitors, or if only you could upload files, I'd go with the "directly-process-way". If this is anything even a little serious, go with the "postponed-process-way". In the first case, it is ridiculously easy to DoS your server.

Comment: Sorry Im confused. The exam will only be used by couple of people. The exam itself won't be a final version. So you are saying the quickest and easiest way is ffmpeg? if so I really need you help in asking how to implement this, I have never used it before and in lehmann terms really want to get this sorted asap for video. If you can show me how to use ffmpeg for videos, I will then work out how to do it for audio files as well. Upvote

Comment: I can post it as seperate question but I really need your help in the separate question in implementing this

Comment: ffmpeg is a commandline video processor for Unix-type OSs. I couldn't say what you will need to transcode your file. ffmpeg has **a lot** of options. Google is your friend. I'll update my answer with an example on how to call a basic ffmpeg transcode.

Comment: You have to install on your server. I don't know what OS it is, but big chance it has ffmpeg in its repositories (except when you are using a Microsoft server).

Comment: I am using a helios server. I am looking at download documentation but which one am I expected to choose from, there is loads: http://ffmpeg.org/download.html